# $f$ convex, is $f(X)$ quasi-integrable if $X$ is?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

I am trying to figure out this:

> Let $f$ be a convex function, and $X$ a quasi-integrable random
>   variable. That means that either $E(X^+(\omega))$ or $E(X^-(\omega))$
>   can be infinity, but not both. Is then $f(X)$ quasi-integrable?

I've tried to find counterexamples, but I wasn't able to do it. If $E(X^+)=\infty, E(X^-)<\infty$, and $f(X)$ should fail to be quasi integrable, I need a convex function with both "large"  positive and negative numbers. So I can't use $x^2$ since it is positive, and I can't use the exponential functions, because they do not get very large negative numbers. I am not really sure which convex function to use.

If I instead try to prove it I need that I get some contradiction if both $E(f(X)^+)=\infty$ and $E(f(X)^-)=\infty$. The expected value of a convex function of a r.v. can be infinite without the r.v. having infinite expectation, so if this is going to go through I somehow need to use that this happens for both the positive and negative parts. But I am not sure how.

The only convex functions I can come up with that takes both unbounded positive and negative values is $f(x)=kx$. If there do not exist other convex functions with this property it should not be difficult to prove it. But this seems implausible, does there exist other convex functions with unbounded positive and negative values?

Do you have any ideas on how to solve this?

Update: I think a counterexample is: $f(x)=e^{-x}, x  \le 0, f(x)=1-x, x >0$. The space is $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),P), P(A) = \int_{A\cap(-\infty,-1)}1/x^3d\lambda+\int_{A\cap (1,\infty)}1/(2x^2)d\lambda, X(\omega)=\omega$.